# What is the @0 used for in SQL queries?

Tags: sql

An example is this:

```
db.QuerySingle("SELECT Email FROM UserProfile WHERE LOWER(Email) = LOWER(@0)", email);
```

Comment: That looks like the name of a variable in SQL Server.  Do you have some more context for your question?

Comment: it is used in the startersite template in WebMatrix, and I can't figure out where it gets its value from

Comment: Then it is supposed to represent a parameter.  WebMatrix is used with SQL Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@` symbol represents a parameter. The word after it, or in this case the number after it, is the name of the parameter.

You can use parameters for a lot of reasons. The main thing is to have a sql statement that doesn't change when the variables / parameters change. This gives the database the opportunity to optimize the executing (for example it doesn't have to recalculate the execution plan).

In this case it has also some security advantages (preventing sql injection).

Comment: what does it mean in this case? where does its value come from. It is from the webmatrix starter razor site if that helps

Comment: In this case it is the `email` variable you pass in. I think WebMatix uses EF, which 'knows' the first parameter starts at 0, etc.